# How to prevent infinite loop fetching data in useEffect() hook with react-redux and eslint (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps) rule enabled

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, eslint, use-effect

I am using react to display my data fetched from API using redux. I would like to fetch data after`<MatchView />` component is mounted and after a button is clicked(in parent component). I have the buttons to change date range(+/- one day from today). The new(changed) date is passed to the `<MatchView />` and I'd like to fetch my data again then(with this new date as query).

Matchview Component:

```
   const MatchesView = ({
      fetchMatches,
      matches = [],
      pending,
      sourceDateRange: [sourceFrom, sourceTo] = [] // <-- This dates are changing in parent component if you click the button
    }) => {
      const sourceISOFormatDateRange = rangeToISOStringWithoutTime(
        sourceFrom,
        sourceTo
      );

  useEffect(() => {
    getMatchesByDateRange(sourceISOFormatDateRange)(fetchMatches); // <-- Fetching function
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [sourceFrom, sourceTo]);

      return (
        <div className="product-list-wrapper">
          {pending ? (
            <h1>Loading...</h1>
          ) : (
            <div>
              <DateHeader dateRange={sourceISOFormatDateRange} />
              <Matches matches={matches} />
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      );
    };

    MatchesView.propTypes = {
      fetchMatches: PropTypes.func,
      matches: PropTypes.array,
      pending: PropTypes.bool,
      sourceDateRange: PropTypes.array
    };

    const mapStateToProps = ({ matchesData }) => ({
      matches: getMatches(matchesData),
      pending: getMatchesPending(matchesData)
    });

    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
      bindActionCreators(
        {
          fetchMatches
        },
        dispatch
      );

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MatchesView);
```

**Just wanted to know why if I add more variables to `[]` in `useEffect(()=>{},[])` it cause infinite loop, fetching the data forever.**

With eslint rule `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` it adds me more variables to `[]` automatically and `useEffect()` looks like below:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getMatchesByDateRange(sourceISOFormatDateRange)(fetchMatches);
  }, [fetchMatches, sourceFrom, sourceISOFormatDateRange, sourceTo]);
```

I have read also to avoid `useEffect()` if possible and use it only if there is a good reason because it can course many unexpected behaviors hard to debug. I think here I cannot avoid using `useEffect()`.

Comment: If you only dispatch on mount so empty array is enough. If you need to fetch depending on some deps then you should include them.`sourceFrom, sourceTo` don't seem like the right choice, only vars/funcs that in the useEffect body

Comment: In my experience I've had the same lint autofix applying parameters to my `useEffect` hook which I tend to avoid as it changes the behaviour.

`useEffect` is triggered every time a value in the dependency array changes. What i think is happening, which we'd need to see the parent and the api call to confirm, is `getMatchesByDateRange` is causing an update that is propagating to the `useEffect` hook seen above.